# Jmeter- How to extract token id from Response Data

Tags: jmeter

This is the response data from which i need to extract token value

```
{
  "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0IjoibXljb21wYW55IiwiZCI6ImhrZy5maXJlYmV0LmRldi5zdXBwb3J0LmNvbSIsInBybSI6WyJsb2c6KiIsInNlc3Npb246Y29ubmVjdCIsInNlc3Npb246dXBsb2FkRmlsZToxMjUyMyIsInNlc3Npb246ZGV2aWNlSW5mbyxsb2dhY3Rpdml0eWV2ZW50LGRldmljZWNhcGFiaWxpdHk6MTM1MTEiXSwianRpIjoiMGVmNmU5OGYtZjQ0My00NmEzLTkxMmMtMDNiNmMyZDFjNzU1IiwiYXBwIjoiVGVzdGFwcCIsInZlciI6IjEiLCJwbHQiOiJBbmRyb2lkIiwiaWF0IjoxNDMyNjE4MDY3LCJhdWQiOiJhcHAiLCJleHAiOjE0MzI2MjUyNjcsImlzcyI6IlN1cHBvcnQuY29tIn0.qkgSrZFoc2MR8xQN0boRd85PcmD1R0xkQjVzKXNv2Uk",
  "session_device_id": "13511",
  "session_id": "12523",
  "relay_config": "tdssd:443",
  "symmetric_key": "dssdFx0=",
  "workflow_version_id": 10s008,
  "unique_connection_id": "fsdsd"
}
```

Currently I am using regular expression extractor

```
token: "(.*?)"
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add closing quotation mark to your regular expression as

```
token": "(.*?)"
```

and use `$1$` as Template

Another option is using [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) which comes with [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) which is more handy to extract stuff from JSON responses. In that case use the following JSON Path query:

```
$..token
```

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for more information on the JSON Path language and few useful examples.

Answer (score 0):

[Extracting token value from the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diuNJ.png)

So here I you used as User id so please change this in token so and use post processor regular expression it will definitely work

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
"token":"(.+?)"
```

in the [JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/).

Answer (score 0):

In regular expression extractor use regular expression as **token": "([^"]+)"** and template **$1$**.
I hope this will help you.